# Outdated Project Assembly loaded when running in Experimental Instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, resharper

I have two C# projects, A and B, in VisualStudio 2010. Project A is a class library. Project B is a ReSharper-Plugin project that references project A (ProjectReference). Both projects compile and worked property when I ran project A in the Experimental Instance.

Now, recently I renamed a static class, with some extension methods, in project A. Both projects still compile. But when I run project B I get an TypeLoadException for the *new* class name. When I change the class's name back, everything works fine again.

My guess is that project B is compiled against the new code, but run against an outdated dll. I tried everything from clear, over rebuild, to restart, but to no avail. I also manually checked that a fresh dll from project A is placed in project B's bin/Debug folder, which is the case. And I copied over the dll manually, after building project A. The problem persists.

Now I ask myself whether there is another location where the dlls are copied to before running the Experimental Instance. Is this the case? If so, where to? Are there any other places where the old version could come form? Or is there even something completely different that could cause the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried re-referencing the DLL from project A into project B?

Comment: Yes, I did that. Before rebuild, after rebuild, and between clear and build...

Comment: What do you mean by ReSharper project - is it a ReSharper plugin? And is the plugin now broken?

Comment: Yes, it's a ReSharper Plugin. What do you mean by broken? As I said, it compiles, but when it run it, it throws a TypeLoadException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself, thanks to the right keywords on Google (*MissingMethodException* and *ProjectReference*) that led me to [a blogpost](http://www.ronaldwidha.net/2010/10/10/missingmethodexception-when-running-unit-test-on-visual-studio/) about a solution to the same symptom. In my case it was not the GAC that caused the problem, but the cached assemblies under

```
C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0Exp\
```

This is the location where all the assemblies of the Experimental Instance go. Here lay an outdated VsExtension that depended on project A and within it there was an outdated copy of project A that was loaded. The loading of the new version from the project reference was simply skipped, since a copy of the assembly (with the same version) was already loaded.

So the problem was ultimately caused by the removal of the extension from my solution. From this point of the extension was no longer updated by VS, but it was also not removed! Lessons learned: After major changes of your infrastructure you may want to delete all cached assemblies below the above path...

Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Did you reference the DLL or the Project? In a Visual Studio Solution you can reference projects. If you reference project A in project B then B should always use the latest code from project A.

Comment: I referenced the project.